# Windows 7 ipconfig is timing out

Tags: windows-7, networking, timeout

I upgraded my machine to use Windows 7 and now experiencing weird network problems. When using "ipconfig /renew" I receive...

> Windows IP Configuration
>
> An error occurred while renewing
>   interface Local Area Connection :
>   unable to contact your DHCP server.
>   Request has timed out. No operation
>   can be performed on Wireless Network
>   Connection while it has its media
>   disconnected.

The weird thing is that I can use my machine fine at work, but at home I cannot get any type of connection. This only began happening after I upgraded to Windows 7. Does anyone know of something Windows 7 may have changed that would cause this type of behavior?

Comment: anything network or interface related showing up in the logs?

Comment: This may or may not be the issue you're having but I had similar symptoms on my Windows 7 box.  I turned off the Power Management setting on the nic "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" and the problem went away.

Comment: http://superuser.com

Comment: Another weird thing is that everything else at home connects fine with my router. My wife's laptop (Windows Vista), my desktop (Mac), my iPhone, the Wii, pretty much everything but my laptop.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's kinda condescending, but you do have a DHCP server running at home...right? =)

Additionally, that error would seem to indicate that the wireless interface is not up. Can you confirm that you are actually attaching to the wireless network as that would obviously be a good first step before getting a DHCP lease.

edit: I second Mitch's suggestion of turning off the box that allows Windows to power down the wireless interface...I've run into many many issues with that box checked.

Comment: +1 for "you do have a DHCP server running at home?" - first principles of troubleshooting, that is. :)

Comment: I do not have a DHCP server running. The cable modem is plugged into my wireless router.

Comment: I have also unchecked the box that allows Windows to power down the wireless interface. Still nothing. My internet connection shows that I am connected to my router but I have no Internet or Network access.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going through a home router, make sure the settings on the router are sane, try doing a full reset of settings for example.